# Use Homebrew's clang from the command line

Tags: macos, clang, homebrew

I used `brew install llvm` to install LLVM 8 and I want to use the command line tools. I have set the path to the `clang` executable (in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`) as suggested by Homebrew and also set LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS as they suggest. When I compile a simple program I get

```
x.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Reading the the docs for `xcrun` and `xcode-select` I feel there should be a simple way to select my LLVM toolchain but I can't figure it out. I have tried changing the `TOOLCHAINS` and `SDKROOT` with no success.

Output of `clang -v -c x.c` for Homebrew's llvm-8

```
clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
 "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/bin/clang-8" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name x.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -ggnu-pubnames -target-linker-version 409.12 -v -coverage-notes-file /tmp/x.gcno -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/clang/8.0.0 -fdebug-compilation-dir /tmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o x.o -x c x.c
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 based upon LLVM 8.0.0 default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/8.0.0/lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
x.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Output of system clang:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.14.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name x.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=10.14 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 450.3 -v -coverage-notes-file /tmp/x.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/include -Wno-atomic-implicit-seq-cst -Wno-framework-include-private-from-public -Wno-atimport-in-framework-header -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -fdebug-compilation-dir /tmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.14.0 -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o x.o -x c x.c
clang -cc1 version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3) default target x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/10.0.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either install missing headers/libraries as [noted in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337940/why-is-usr-include-missing-i-have-xcode-and-command-line-tools-installed-moja).

Alternatively, you should point `clang` to another 'sysroot', e.g.:

```
clang -isysroot `xcrun --show-sdk-path` hello.c
```